# Use math in the fields

Tags: entities

I want to use some math function in the field.
Is there any editor to support all of the mathematics functions?
For Example log,Radical and etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module, which allows you to write custom PHP functions to determine field values.  You will of course need to be familiar with PHP.

Comment: Oh,I'm not as well as that in the PHP.Is there any better way to using math in the field?

Comment: @mahdialikhasi If you want to actually evaluate the functions (and not just display the values), I think you will have to use PHP...

Comment: @mahdialikhasi PHP isn't hard, really. If you want to sum two values, all you need to do is `$a + $b`, and so on :) Programming languages are a way to describe math you want to your machine, all the rest is just a side effect. In my country you could probably find a contractor who would write it for you for less than $20 (if calculation is simple, it would be way less than an hour of work) so I don't believe anyone would invest $ thousands in his time to write a module to make it "simpler" = embed math-oriented programming language into PHP.

Comment: I know the PHP, but not very well to making a module or writing a very good PHP function. But in soon I will learn it!

Comment: You can always try to write a function with Computed Field and then ask another question here if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) module may do what you want. It is a simpler alternative to Computed Field that does not require PHP knowledge or the insecure PHP Filter module.

> The Math Field module defines a new field type to dynamically calculate values on entity forms. This is an alternative to [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field)
>   that does not require the use of PHP Filter.
>
> Math fields are dynamically updated on the entity form as soon as any required fields are populated. The result is stored in the database when the form is submitted.
>
> Math Field uses the cTools math expression library and supports all the basic operators (+-*/^) as well as constants 'pi' and 'e' […]